# Can I make this xpath search faster?

Tags: xml, xpath, php-5.2

```xml
<root>
  <a auto='1'>
    <b>
      <c auto="1">
        <d auto="1"></d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e auto="1">
      <f>
        <g auto="1"></g>
      </f>
    </e>
  </a>
</root>
```

Find all elements that

1. Is descendant of context element
2. Have `auto` attribute
3. Highest level (have no ancestor with `auto` attribute between self and the context element)

So, if the context node is `a` then `c` and `e` should be returned.

I've implemented it in my php class:

```php
$tempId='XDFAY69LA';
$this->setAttribute('tempId',$tempId);
$path=".//\*[@auto and not(ancestor::\*[@auto and ancestor::\*[@tempId='$tempId']])]";
$ar=$this->getElementsByXPath($path);
$this->removeAttribute('tempId');
```

But I found the query is slowly, maybe .. , because the query is too complex?, And is there a way that do a better job?

---

I wrote a testing, please have a look:

```php
<?php
  $xml='
    <root>
      <a auto="1" tempId="current">
        <b>
          <c auto="1">
            <d auto="1"></d>
          </c>
        </b>
        <e auto="1">
          <f>
            <g auto="1"></g>
          </f>
        </e>
      </a>
    </root> ';

  $doc=new DomDocument();
  $tempId='XDFAY69LA';
  $doc->loadXml($xml);
  $domxpath=new DOMXPath($doc);
  $a=$domxpath->query('a')->item(0);
  $path=".//*[@auto and not(ancestor::*[@auto and ancestor::*[@tempId='$tempId']])]";
  $start=microtime(true);
  for($n=0;$n<1000;$n++){ //run 1000 times
    $a->setAttribute('tempId',$tempId);
    $ar=$domxpath->query($path,$a);
    $a->removeAttribute('tempId');
    for($i=0;$i<$ar->length;$i++){
      $node=$ar->item($i);
      //echo $node->tagName . "\n";
    }
  }
  $cost=round(1000 * (microtime(true)-$start));
  echo "time cost: $cost";
?>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a shorter XPath expression and for a demonstration of a much faster solution using XSLT and keys. If you are forbidden to use XSLT, you can implement a similar solution using hash tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
.//*[@auto and $tempId = ancestor::*[@auto][1]/@tempId]
```

This selects all descendent elements (of the context node) that have an `auto` attribute and whose first ancestor that has `auto` attribute also has a `tempId` attribute with the same value as that of the `tempId` attribute of the context node (the latter being stored in the `$tempId` variable).

Here we assume that no two different elements have the same value of their `tempId` attributes.

**A quick XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="a">
   <xsl:variable name="tempId" select="@tempId"/>

     <xsl:copy-of select=
      ".//*[@auto and $tempId = ancestor::*[@auto][1]/@tempId]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <a auto="1" tempId="current">
        <b>
            <c auto="1">
                <d auto="1"></d>
            </c>
        </b>
        <e auto="1">
            <f>
                <g auto="1"></g>
            </f>
        </e>
    </a>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the two elements `c` and `e`) is produced**:

```
<c auto="1">
   <d auto="1"/>
</c>
<e auto="1">
   <f>
      <g auto="1"/>
   </f>
</e>
```

**The performance cannot be improved only within the XPath expression** and the inefficiency is due to having to use the `//` XPath pseudo-operator.

**If using XSLT, it is possible to have an efficient solution using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kfirstDescendents" match="*[@auto]"
  use="generate-id(ancestor::*[@auto][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="a">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "key('kfirstDescendents', generate-id())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation produces the same result as the first, and is significantly faster** on documents with many nested elements that have an `auto` attribute.

If use of XSLT is absolutely ruled out, one can achieve the same effect as XSLT keys with the use of hash tables (sorry, don't know PHP).

Comment: Yeah! I like your expression, though it seems dosn't improve speed much as you say.  I am not using xslt, but I think I need learn about it and your suggest about hash table now, thanks for reply!

Comment: @fclddcn: I never saud the expression was fast -- on the contrary, I said it was slow and the only way to get faster execution is via caching (indexing, xslt keys, hash-tables otherwise).

Comment: I see, sorry for my poor english, I means 'the same as you say' :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your XPath:

```
 .//*[@auto and not(ancestor::*[@auto and ancestor::*[@tempId='$tempId']])]
```

what about:

```
 .//*[@auto and not(ancestor::*[@auto][ancestor::*[@tempId='$tempId']])]
```

or even,

```
 .//*[@auto and count(ancestor::*[@auto][ancestor::*[@tempId='$tempId']])=0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this taught me a new form of xpath

Answer (score 0):

My idea to simplify it a little.

```
$path=".//*[@auto and not(ancestor::*[@auto and not(@tempId='$tempId'))]";
```

"ancestor::*[@tempId='$tempId']"

to

"not(@tempId='$tempId')"

---

//edit content:eliminated verbose

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think this one is not do the same thing as mine, and not a valid xpath expression

Comment: I'm blind. if 'a' has ancestor with '@auto' attribute, my code is unmatch, sorry.

Comment: Take it easy, I made many mistake about this problem also. thanks.